# From Span To linear Equstions

Tags: linear-algebra

> Write the following vector space in the form of linear equations
>
> $${\rm Span}\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
> 2 & 0 \\
> 1 & 3
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & -1 \\
> 1 & 0 
> \end{pmatrix}\Bigg\}$$

So we need to find a homogeneous system of linear equations s.t $Ax=0$ where

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
a+2b+c & a-c \\
b+c & a+3b
\end{pmatrix}$$

But how can it be done?

Comment: Now you have four equations, set them all equal to zero and solve.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Why to zero?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Ok got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the system $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
a+2b+c & a-c \\
b+c & a+3b
\end{pmatrix}$$

You simply have to make a linear homogeneous system like this:
$$\begin{cases}a+2b+c=0\\a-c=0\\b+c=0\\a+3b=0\end{cases}=\begin{cases}a=-(c+2b)\\a=c\\c=-b\\a=-3b\end{cases}=\begin{cases}a=0\\b=0\\c=0\end{cases}$$

This means that the four vectors are linearly indipendent.